# Angular 5 - Issue when passing modified values in FormGroup between components with @Input

Tags: angular, angular-forms, formgroups

### Context

I'm trying to use the same `FormGroup` between two components, but it does not work well, so I'm trying to figure out where I'm wrong.

I have 2 different components with forms for editing the same content, and I want to switch between the components. The idea was to use the same form group, to share modifications between components.

### Issue

The parent component creates the `FormGroup`, gives it to the *component A*, the data is modified, the `FormGroup` is touched, but when I switch components and pass it to the second *component B*, the `FormGroup` has the initial values, untouched.

I checked in the parent component that the `FormGroup` has modified values, and that it is touched.

I tried something like that for debugging:

```html
<div *ngIf="isComponentB">
    <componentB [(form)]="formGroup" [formData]="formGroup.value"></componentB>
</div>
```

In the *componentB*'s `ngOnInit`:

- in `formData`, I can see the modified values from the *componentA*
- in `form.value`, it's the initial untouched data, and form is marked as untouched.

I don't really see why I have this behavior... It's like the `FormGroup` was not updated, expect that it is, as it's `value` is changed.

Any clue about what I'm missing?

> In fact I was missing that the data was reset in a subform that was supposed to only initialize it. So I moved the initialization at higher level.

Comment: is it possible to provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @FranklinPious Well, my bad, it was a good suggestion... I managed to do a stackblitz without being able to reproduce the issue, so it was somewhere else and I find out the solution in the end. I guess it validates to try to reproduce the issue with a simple example.